# JSON data to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

When I do JArray.toSource(), I get this:-

```
[{selectionID:"1", cnt:"5"}, {selectionID:"2", cnt:"2"}, {selectionID:"3", cnt:"1"}]
```

How can I convert JArray to format like this:-

```
[[1,5],[2,2],[3,1]]
```

in JavaScript.

Eventually I want `newJArray.toSource()` become `[[1,5],[2,2],[3,1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pimvdb's solution is very nice. My comment is that in this particular case this is enough:

```
array.map(function(arrayItem) {
    return [arrayItem.selectionID, arrayItem.cnt];
});
```

It is uglier (more specific), but my gut feeling is that it's much more efficient (and sometimes that matters).

Comment: newJArray= JArray.map(function(){ 
  return [JArray.selectionID, JArray.cnt];
});
become [[(void 0), (void 0)], [(void 0), (void 0)], [(void 0), (void 0)]]

Am I missing something here where JArray[??].selectionID

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.keys` which returns the keys, and `map` to map the array as such:

```
array.map(function(arrayItem) {
  return Object.keys(arrayItem).map(function(objectKey) {
    return +arrayItem[objectKey]; // convert to number
  });
});
```

Basically, you replace each element in the array with the values of the object.